# The second contract is not getting deployed in migration

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration, truffle-contract, truffle-test

```
const Input = artifacts.require("Input");
const Register = artifacts.require("Register");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Input, "test_name")
  .then(async()=>{
    let instance = await Input.deployed();
    let name = instance.name();
    deployer.deploy(Register, name)
  })
};
```

Tried using this during migration to get a public string variable from the first contract as the constructor argument of the second contract.

There're no errors but the second contract is not getting deployed...

please kindly answer this anyone.

Comment: so what is the return value from the deploying transaction when you do a `debug.traceTransaction()` of the hash of the second transaction????

Comment: how do you know the second contract is not deployed ? can you put a log after the second contract is deployed in a `.then` callback function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot use `Input.deployed()` inside an script that deploys `Input`.

A workaround is to create an instance at `Input.address`, e.g. `await Input.at(Input.address)`:

```
module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Input, "test_name").then(async () => {
    let instance = await Input.at(Input.address)
    let name = await instance.name()
    deployer.deploy(Register, name)
  })
}
```

Comment: thanx a lot bro!